# Best way to select by parent by grandparent...in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given the hierarchy (pseudocode for clarity):

```
Grandparent:
    name (unique)

Parent:
    name (unique)
    grandparent

Child:
    name (unique)
    parent
```

Given you know the names of a child, parent, grandparent combination, what is the best way (in SQLAlchemy) to select a child? I now do three subsequent queries (first grandparent by grandparent_name, then parent by grandparent and name, finally child by name and parent). Is there maybe a way to do this in one select query instead?

(PS: Of course I could give Child a unique ID and select by that, but it seems cleaner to select a child by parent by grandparent)

Comment: Use joins and filter.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
session.query(Child).join(Parent).join(Grandparent).\
    filter(Grandparent.name==grandparent_name).\
    filter(Parent.name==parent_name).\
    filter(Child.name==name).\
    first()
```